# Is there a word that has the same -er sound pronunciation in all both British and American accents

Tags: pronunciation, accent, endings

Most words with `-er` ending, sound different in British and American accent. In British it’s “a”, in American it’s “e”(don’t know how to correctly write transcription ).

But is there word, that has the same “e” sound in different accents, or vice-versa, a word, that has the same “a” pronunciation?

Like, *water* sounds different in America and Britian(there is also difference in “t” pronunciation). In American it’s like a “wodae”, and in British accent it’s “wotuh”. Is there a word with `-er` ending that all people pronounce the same?

Comment: I think you're wrong in your premise here, and the principal difference is rhoticity (whether the *-r* is pronounced). The *-er* in *writer* is very similar, apart from AmE tending to /əʳ/ whereas BrE tends to /ə/. And both accents have exceptions. However, others may be able to show that my rudimentary analysis is wrong.

Comment: Could you give us some examples of what you've observed?

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul what do You mean?

Comment: *Most words with -er ending, sound different in British and American accent. In British it’s “a”, in American it’s “e”* —> Examples of this kind of words.

Comment: *Is there a word with -er ending that all people spell the same?* -> water, matter, later etc etc etc.

Comment: *Like, water sounds different in America and Britian(there is also difference in “t” pronunciation). In American it’s like a “wodae”, and in British accent it’s “wotuh”* ---> It depends on rhoticity (as Andrew Leach said in their comment). The t in British accent is true t while in AE, it sounds more like d and is called 'tap t' or 'flap t'.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul, well the word “Rhoticity” is actually untranslatable into Russian, and there is no Russian variant of the Rhoticity wiki page, but as far as I understood, this word was invented for guys, who, for some reasons don’t want to use word “Accent”. But they actually have the same meaning

Comment: Standard British English is non-rhotic which means that speakers of BE don't pronounce r unless it's followed by a vowel sound. Whereas in AmE, the r is pronounced in all positions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *In British it’s “a”, in American it’s “e”*.

Comment: _Rhoticity_ is _not_ a synonym of _accent_, it's one particular feature of the English of some groups of speakers.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul, so I just wondering, if there are words with -ed , that in all accents pronounced the same. Maybe it’s a surname, like, I don’t know, maybe Americans also say “Hitluh”, not “Hitleeeeeer”

Comment: @АртурКлочко, It depends on dialect. if the dialect is rhotic, the r in Hitler is pronounced. If the dialect is non-rhotic, the r is not pronounced (unless it's prevocalic) so Hitler is pronounced as Hitl**uh**.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul, so Your answer is no - there are no words on -er that are spelled independently on accent/dialect/country?

Comment: Spelling is the same, pronunciation is different (depends on dialect).

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul lol, I always thought “to spell” means “to say”/“to pronounce “ . I meant exactly pronunciation, sorry

Comment: No problem. :) Pronunciation depends on the speaker and the variety of English they speak.